# Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies

Tags: angular, npm

I found the following problem while installing Angular.

```
$ node -v
v9.10.1
$ npm -v
5.8.0
$ ng --version

Unable to find "@angular/cli" in devDependencies.

Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest"


    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 9.10.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: undefined
...


typescript: error
webpack: error
```

**As you can see, the Angular version is "undefined", cli and typescript, and webpack is an error. This is my problem.** I tried to create a project.

```
$ ng new test-proj
You cannot use the new command inside an Angular CLI project.
```

I followed [Angular guide page](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart) but I did not succeed.

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ ... skip ... "
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": " ... skip ... "
  },
  "homepage": " ... skip ... ",
  "dependencies": {
    "formidable": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "description": ""
}
```

Please help me.
What's wrong?

Comment: From that error it seems you're trying to create a new project whilst already in the directory structure of another project.

Comment: Following @rrd, simply go back from one folder with `cd ../`

Comment: Did you installed angular/cli globally??

Comment: @GavishiddappaGadagi sure. I installed globally.

Comment: We removed `@angular/cli` from devDependencies inside `package.json`. Then I created the project again.`Unable to find "@ angular / cli" in devDependencies.

Comment: When input ng new (proj name), `Please take the following steps to avoid issues:
"npm install --save-dev @ angular / cli @ latest"` is displayed, but the project has been successfully created. But I still do not know the correct solution.